# Trying to Gradually Increase Motor Speed

Tags: voltage, dc-motor, motor-controller

**In Short:**

I'm trying to create a soft start mechanism so that **when a 12V DC source is turned initially connected, the motor takes 5-7 seconds to get up to full speed**.

**Longer Explanation:**

A lot of other posts deal with preventing inrush surges on the order of milliseconds, but I could find very few that want a 5-7 second increase time. It can be linear increase in motor speed, or whatever is easiest to build, as long as it is gradual and the motor doesn't run at full speed initially. The motor will draw about 2A current, 3A max. I don't want to use a microcontroller because it seems redundant in this situation.

What chips/parts/circuits should I consider if I want to achieve this?

```
 Am I wanting some sort of variable current limiter?
 Some sort of inductor flyback diode thing?
 Some RC rig with a capacitor in parallel with the 12v source?
 Some thermistor circuit?
 Is there a 12v 3A motor controller than can do this automatically for me?
```

I'm not experienced with EE, and I would appreciate any guidance on how you would implement a circuit like that. The main thing that I'm trying to optimize for is ease of building the circuit, and reliability.

Comment: You can alter the timing on inrush circuits so link to one you found and someone will advise you what to do.

Comment: I think you want a speed controller that has an acceleration adjustment. That would be a standard feature for an industrial motor controller. I would think it would be a small enhancement for the most basic speed controller circuit.

Comment: Thanks so much for your responses! I'll look into STALL CURRENT for sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a microcontroller, this is a piece of cake. You would just implement a variable PWM drive.

To do it with 'a circuit', you'll probably need a transistor with a capacitor on its gate and a couple of resistors. Piece of cake to put together but the downside is during those 5-7 seconds, the transistor will be sinking a lot of power i.e. it'll get hot. You'll need a big transistor and a heatsink. PWM from a microcontroller would physically be a much smaller implementation and nothing would get hot.

Note that you don't care about the nominal operating current of the motor (3 A). You'll care about the STALL CURRENT. When the motor isn't running at all, and you start to apply voltage, until the motor begins to spin it's basically a short-circuit. It'll probably try to draw several times the nominal i.e. 8-10 A maybe.

The datasheet for the motor will give you the stall current.

[Here's](http://www.homemade-circuits.com/pwm-motor-soft-start-circuit/) a circuit that does a PWM soft-start with no microcontroller.